# How can I migrate merge requests from one git server to another?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

Our team moved from a git server hosted at site A to another one at site B. They were able to move the source code, and all its branches correctly. But we couldn't find any way to move the Merge Requests that the team had opened on branches when we were working on site A to site B.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Many of our Merge requests have conversations in them that are important to maintain history of how the code changed.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the software running at A and B. Gitlab? Stash? ...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are three ways

1. with access to the server you can

   1.1. do a whole backup of the server and delete all unneeded projects

   1.2. copy the underlaying database and delete all unneeded projects
2. with api access you can

   iterate over your projects and their merge requests and copy them one by one via api to the other server. See [Gitlab API merge requests](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html)